# Subscriber in sample_app of android_ndk not working

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I'm currently trying to port a c++ Desktop Applicatioon to Android. I have been able to build the andoird_ndk sample app following this tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/android_ndk/Tutorials/SimpleNativeActivityApplication

But when I start the app and publish a message from my workstation as described in the tutorial, the callback is never called, as i have verified with logcat.

To check the general connection, i have modified the test.cpp file to publish a single message before entering the while-loop and i am able to receive this message on my workstation.

Does anyone have an idea, what could cause this issue?

(Since I'm new to ROS, tell me if you need further information)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243252/subscriber-in-sample_app-of-android_ndk-not-working/) by [koeberlue](https://answers.ros.org/users/27918/koeberlue/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some debugging i found out that my network was not set up properly. I had to set the ROS_IP environment variable to my local ip.

For further information read http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup

---

Originally posted by [koeberlue](https://answers.ros.org/users/27918/koeberlue/) with karma: 26 on 2016-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xy1zzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25141/xy1zzz/) on 2017-02-04**:
hi everyone,i have the same problem,when i run roswtf,it says:

```
Found 1 error(s).

ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /rosjava/talker->/android_ndk_native_cpp (/chatter)
 * /rostopic_7280_1486193220744->/android_ndk_native_cpp (/chatter)
```